# Sencha Touch: Spanish Accent characters wrongly encoded in app.js on WP8 Build

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, character-encoding, sencha-touch, html-escape-characters

My App has spanish accents on it, such as: Sesión

When I build and compile my App natively for iOS and Android (in OSX environment), accent show perfectly encoded in app.js, and display beautifully on the App running natively on the devices.

When I build and compile my App natively for Windows Phone 8 (in Windows 8.1 environment), accents show wrongly incoded in app.js such as: sesi�n, and display erroneously on WP8 device as well as on IE.

How can I compile my App for WP8 so that the accent characters show correct?

Thank you!

Comment: What encoding is the course in?

Comment: What do you mean by "the course"?. index.html has UTF-8 encoding set in the meta tag, also the files are saved in UTF-8 encoding as well.

Comment: I meant "source", it was a typo.

Comment: I have the same problem. also with euro symbol

Comment: Unfortunately we haven't found a solution for this yet. To by pass this, we ended up changing manually all accents in the file :(

Comment: I using actually this site http://0xcc.net/jsescape/ to convert the chars. The \xXX and the &#DDDD; method convert worked